# Drupal: Cannot save any nodes of certain content types, used to work

Tags: drupal-6

Whenever I save or create a node of a certain user-defined type, I am back in the edit window instead of switching to the first tab labeled view. All my fields (body, title etc. are as they were and no message appears, neither directly on the page nor in the watchdog database log. The validation is working, though, because I see those 'required' messages as soon as I try to save without Title for example.

The strange thing is that when I create a new content type, or use the predefined story and page types, I can edit and create nodes. In the latter case, Drupal answers with an 302 redirect, whereas with the proplematic content types, only a 200 HTTP status is returned.

The issue doesn't seem to be related to either JavaScript (on or off, no difference), Browser (tried Chrome and Firefox) or WYSIWYG (used input formats with and without).

I'm using Drupal 6.22 and the CCK. I have about 7 content types, some of them with fields. I am not using Rules, but a multitude of modules, all of which are up-to-date. I will post a list if this issue can't be solved otherwise.

I have spend the last hours trying to figure this out, both by looking at my installation (settings, database) and by searching Google & Co.
Any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like a failed validation that isn't showing the validation error.

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to debug this? I deactivated CSS in hope to see something, but no :-(

Comment: Provided that you haven't written any of your own code/module with respect to problematic content type, turn off as many non-core modules as possible and try to enable them one by one to see if any of them are causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation appeared because Drupal translated both the Upload and the Save button to one word, Speichern. The FileField issue tracker contains the corresponding thread: http://drupal.org/node/684426

The ImageField and Locale modules, along with a language such as German or Finnish were partly responsible for the trouble.